# from excel function sumprod to dax powerbi or power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

help me please to find the answer to my work task

```
type here
```

let
// Étape 1: Obtention de la source de données (remplacez "Data inbound" par le nom de votre table)
Source = #"Data inbound",

```
// Étape 2: Ajouter une colonne personnalisée pour calculer le nombre de rappels dans les 48 heures
AddRappels48H = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Rappels48H", each
    let
        currentOriginator = [Originator],
        currentDateTime = [Datetime],
        rappels48H = Table.SelectRows(Source,
            each [Originator] = currentOriginator
            and [Datetime] >= currentDateTime
            and [Datetime] <= currentDateTime + #duration(2, 0, 0, 0)
            and [Answered]
        ),
        countRappels48H = Table.RowCount(rappels48H)
    in
        countRappels48H
)
```

in
AddRappels48H

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
=Table.AddColumn(Source, "Rappels48H",  (x) => Table.SelectRows(Source2, each each [Originator] = x[Originator] and
```

And so on

Comment: I have the "Data inbound" table which consists of:
1st column "Originator"=customer's phone number Type Any
2nd column "Date week"=customer's calls date type Date
3rd column "Answered"= Integer type
I want to create a column in DAX power bi desktop for: the sum of "Answered" by "Originator" repeated from the "Date week" row of the Originator >= and < "Date week "+2 days.

Comment: Your question has code in M not DAX. You sure you want a DAX answer ?  Either way I don't understand your comment so perhaps someone else will help you